# Two seperate traps, one to catch all exits and one to catch error exits

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to have two traps in my script, one that catches all exits and one that catches all error or non 0 exits.

This is what I tried. I expected it to run the `broad_func` under all exits and the error function under only error exits. But it only runs `broad_func`.

```
trap broad_func EXIT
trap error_func ERR
```

Comment: Works fine for me.  Maybe you should supply a little more info on what you expected, what it actually did, and exactly what you mean by "non 0 exits". The EXIT trap only fires when the context shell is closing - it doesn't trigger at the end of child processes.  That would be a CHLD trap, a "real" signal (unlike the other two), which might drag you into the morass of whether or not the signal is consumed by the trap and needs to be "re-thrown"...

Comment: Works for me. error_func is executed on error, broad_func is executed on all exits. Did you enable errexit?